# How to search rows in DataFrame and return the first element found in a dictionary to a new column using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
print(df):

# Output
                        Text         
0  Melbourne. Adelaide. Brisbane.     
1  Sydney. Adelaide. Gold Coast.       
2  Gold Coast. Brisbane. Melbourne.   
3  Sydney. Melbourne. Brisbane.
```

I also have a dictionary

```
print(dict):

{'VIC': ['Melbourne'], 'SA': ['Adelaide'], 'QLD': ['Brisbane','Gold Coast'], 'NSW': ['Sydney']}
```

The output i am trying to create is:

```
print(df):

                       Text               VIC              SA              QLD                NSW
0  Melbourne. Adelaide. Brisbane.        Melbourne.       Adelaide.         Brisbane.        
1  Sydney. Adelaide. Gold Coast.                          Adelaide.         Gold Coast.      Sydney.  
2  Gold Coast. Brisbane. Melbourne.     Melbourne.                          Brisbane.        
3  Sydney. Melbourne. Brisbane.         Melbourne.       Adelaide.          Brisbane.
```

When 2 items appear from same state (eg in `df index 2`) i would like to show Brisbane instead of Gold Coast because it is appears first in the `dict`

I have used the following code which works to put a 1 or 0 if the string is found::

```
    for index in df.index:
        for key, s_elements in dict.items():
            df.at[index, key] = (lambda: 1 if any([s in df['Text'][index] for s in s_elements]) else 0)()
```

print(df):

```
                       Text               VIC              SA              QLD                NSW
0  Melbourne. Adelaide. Brisbane.           1               1               1                  0
1  Sydney. Adelaide. Gold Coast.                            1               1                  1
2  Gold Coast. Brisbane. Melbourne.         1               0               1                  0
3  Sydney. Melbourne. Brisbane.             1               0               1                  1
```

Which works well but i am trying to get the name of the city found in the comlumn (using the first one element in each key).

Can anyone help with what adjustment i need to make to get the names to appear as opposed to the number? I have tried `lambda: s_elements` instead of `lambda: 1` but getting a `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Any help would be fantastic! thanks very much!

Comment: Is this a class assignment? If it is then fine. If not  why would the dictionary be a dictionary of lists with each list having one item? Why would Melbourne have a dot after it? Just wondering?

Comment: @wwnde To be honest this was the way I thought it would work best. I have a csv where column A is the group name (eg VIC) with each other column representing values that belong to that group. So then I have imported this csv into a dictionary to use from there. Corrected mistake for the dot with Melbourne

Comment: Was just wondering why you put your dict as it is and not {'Melbourne':'VIC', 'Adelaide':'SA', 'Brisbane':'QLD','Gold Coast':'QLD', 'Sydney':'NSW'} . Because the way it is someone has to reverse key values to map it to the df which is computationally intensive

Comment: Thanks @wwnde so if i changed the dict to the other way it be better in the long run? I have potentially 500,000 rows of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy task, but one way is to first compile a regex pattern for `extractall`:

```
s = {'VIC': ['Melbourne'], 'SA': ['Adelaide'], 'QLD': ['Brisbane', 'Gold Coast'], 'NSW': ['Sydney']}

pattern = "|".join(f"({x})" for x in ("|".join(i) for i in s.values()))
```

This gives `(Melbourne)|(Adelaide)|(Brisbane|Gold Coast)|(Sydney)`, but you also want precedence of `Brisbane` over `Gold Coast`, which will require this pattern instead:

```
pattern2 = "(Melbourne)|(Adelaide)|(Brisbane|Gold Coast(?!.*Brisbane))|(Sydney)"
```

Anyway, with either pattern, you can use `str.extractall` to obtain the matches, flatten the rows using `groupby` and `first`, and then `concat` with the original df and also rename the columns:

```
ref = (df["Text"].str.extractall(pattern2).reset_index()
       .groupby("level_0").first()
       .rename(columns={v:k for k,v in zip(s.keys(), range(0,4))})
       .reset_index(drop=True))

print (pd.concat([df, ref.iloc[:,1:]],axis=1))

                               Text        VIC        SA         QLD     NSW
0    Melbourne. Adelaide. Brisbane.  Melbourne  Adelaide    Brisbane     NaN
1     Sydney. Adelaide. Gold Coast.        NaN  Adelaide  Gold Coast  Sydney
2  Gold Coast. Brisbane. Melbourne.  Melbourne       NaN    Brisbane     NaN
3      Sydney. Melbourne. Brisbane.  Melbourne       NaN    Brisbane  Sydney
```

Comment: Thanks @Henry Yik that looks like it makes sense to me. As wwnde suggested above should i reverse my dictionary for this code to run better?

Comment: I don't think it matters unless it is a huge dictionary. I prefer your current setup so it is easier to group those related together when compiling a regex pattern.

Comment: thanks @Henry Yik. I have applied it to my case (on a bigger dataset) and looks to be working. The only things ive found: i have 13 columns so i changed the range `range(0,4)` to `0,13` however after the first 4 columns the rest of the data is now offset by 1 column so the last column (13 is in the 14th column). Any ideas there?

Comment: You can check the result of `df["Text"].str.extractall(pattern2).reset_index().groupby("level_0").first()` and rename accurately.

Comment: Is there any particular reason it would put the correct heading name in but the results are shifted to the next cell? Eg what is happening is the `SA` column is blank but the `QLD` column has `Adelaide` in it and the `NSW` column `Brisbane` etc. But VIC is fine

Comment: That would probably be a `regex` pattern problem. It would be easier if you didn't have preferences of location over others. What is your current regex pattern on your real data?

Comment: I have tried just using `pattern` instead of `pattern2` which i get the same where it shifts after the 3rd column (but column names stay in correct spot). The `pattern` of my real data is too big to post here unfortuantely

Comment: I can't really tell with no actual data, but if its the only problem you are having, perhaps [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) it back to the correct place.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help @Henry Yik

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt : take data out of pandas, do the cleanups, then pull back into a dataframe. since it is strings, it should be fast. but concat twice? hmmmm. anyways, here goes:

```
#flip dictionary, so values become keys and vice versa : 
repl = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    for ent in v:
        repl[ent] = k

repl
{'Melbourne': 'VIC',
 'Adelaide': 'SA',
 'Brisbane': 'QLD',
 'Gold Coast': 'QLD',
 'Sydney': 'NSW'}

#get out of dataframe
res = df.Text.str.split('.',expand=True).to_numpy().tolist()
print(res)
[['Melbourne', ' Adelaide', ' Brisbane'],
 ['Sydney', ' Adelaide', ' Gold Coast'],
 ['Gold Coast', ' Brisbane', ' Melbourne'],
 ['Sydney', ' Melbourne', ' Brisbane']]

#cleanups here
res = [[entry.strip() for entry in ent] for ent in res]
res = [[(k,repl.get(k)) for k in ent] for ent in res]
#get rid of Gold Coast if Brisbane is also in the same space
[ent.remove(('Gold Coast','QLD')) if ('Gold Coast','QLD') in ent and ('Brisbane','QLD') in ent else ent for ent in res]
res = (zip(*ent) for ent in res) #this gets cities into a group and states in another group per row

cols = ['VIC','SA','QLD','NSW']
#get dataframe
out = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(start,index=end).reindex(cols,axis=0).T for start,end in res), ignore_index=True)

#merge back with main df
pd.concat((df,out),axis=1)


       Text                          VIC          SA         QLD    NSW
0   Melbourne. Adelaide. Brisbane   Melbourne   Adelaide    Brisbane    NaN
1   Sydney. Adelaide. Gold Coast    NaN Adelaide    Gold Coast  Sydney
2   Gold Coast. Brisbane. Melbourne Melbourne   NaN Brisbane    NaN
3   Sydney. Melbourne. Brisbane Melbourne   NaN Brisbane    Sydney
```